# Custom view not invalidating

Tags: java, android

I know this question is duplicated but i could not find a suitable answer for my code please see below i have a custom view(A graph)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BarView extends View {


    private final int TEXT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#9B9A9B");
    private final int LINE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#9B9A9B");
    private final int BAR_RIGHT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#e45d97");
    private final int BAR_LEFT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0");
    private ArrayList<Integer> dataList;
    private Paint textPaint;
    private Paint rightBarPaint;
    private Paint leftBarPaint;
    private Paint linePaint;
    private Rect rect;

    private ArrayList<String> leftTextList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //    Bar
    private int barWidth;
    private ArrayList<Integer> barTop = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> barBottom = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> barPercentage = new ArrayList<>();
    //Bar box calculation
    private int totalViewHeight;
    private int totalViewWidth;
    private int leftViewPadding;
    private int topViewPadding;
    private int rightViewPadding;
    private int bottomViewPadding;
    private int totalBarRatio = 60;
    private int totalBottomCount = 6;
    private int centerX;
    private int leftX;


    public BarView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    //Initialize components
    public BarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        rightBarPaint = new Paint();
        rightBarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rightBarPaint.setColor(BAR_RIGHT_COLOR);
        leftBarPaint = new Paint(rightBarPaint);
        leftBarPaint.setColor(BAR_LEFT_COLOR);
        rect = new Rect();
        leftViewPadding = GraphUtils.dip2px(context, 5);
        int textSize = GraphUtils.sp2px(context, 12);
        barWidth = GraphUtils.dip2px(context, 22);
        topViewPadding = GraphUtils.dip2px(context, 50);
        bottomViewPadding = GraphUtils.dip2px(context, 50);
        rightViewPadding = GraphUtils.dip2px(context, 15);
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textPaint.setTypeface(Util.setCustomFont(context));
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        linePaint.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    /**
     * dataList will be reset when called is method.
     *
     * @param leftStringList The String ArrayList in the left.
     */
    public void setLeftTextList(ArrayList<String> leftStringList) {
//        this.dataList = null;
        this.leftTextList = leftStringList;
        setMinimumWidth(2);
    }

    /**
     * @param list The ArrayList of Integer with the range of [0-max].
     */
    public void setDataList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        dataList = list;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        totalViewHeight = getHeight();
        totalViewWidth = getWidth();
        //Draw OuterBox
        drawOuterBox(canvas);
        int i = 0;
        if (dataList != null && !dataList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Integer data : dataList) {
                //Draw left graph value
                if (data < totalBarRatio / 2 && data >= 0) {
                    rect.set(barPercentage.get(data - 1), barTop.get(i), centerX, barBottom.get(i));
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, leftBarPaint);
                }
                if (data > totalBarRatio / 2 && data <= totalBarRatio) {
                    //Draw Right graph Value
                    rect.set(centerX, barTop.get(i), barPercentage.get(data - 1), barBottom.get(i));
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, rightBarPaint);

                }
                i++;
            }
        }


    }


    private void drawOuterBox(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw Horizontal lines
        leftX = leftViewPadding + Math.round(getHighestLeftTextWidth()) + leftViewPadding;
        int availableHeight = (totalViewHeight - (topViewPadding + bottomViewPadding));
        int unitHeight = availableHeight / leftTextList.size() + 1;
        if (leftTextList != null && !leftTextList.isEmpty()) {
            //Draw first line with top padding
            canvas.drawLine(leftX, topViewPadding, totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, topViewPadding, linePaint);
            barTop.add(topViewPadding + unitHeight / 4);
            barBottom.add(topViewPadding + (unitHeight / 4) * 3);
            for (int i = 1; i < leftTextList.size(); i++) {
                barTop.add(topViewPadding + unitHeight * i + unitHeight / 4);
                barBottom.add(topViewPadding + unitHeight * i + (unitHeight / 4) * 3);
                canvas.drawLine(leftX, topViewPadding + unitHeight * i, totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, topViewPadding + unitHeight * i, linePaint);
            }
            //Draw last line with top padding
            canvas.drawLine(0, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, totalViewWidth, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, linePaint);
        }
        //Draw Vertical lines
        //Right line
        canvas.drawLine(totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, topViewPadding, totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, linePaint);
        //Center Line
        centerX = (totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding + leftX) / 2;
        canvas.drawLine(centerX, topViewPadding, centerX, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, linePaint);
        //Left Vertical Line
        canvas.drawLine(leftX, topViewPadding, leftX, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, linePaint);

//        Draw left Text
        if (leftTextList != null && !leftTextList.isEmpty()) {
            int i = 1;
            for (String s : leftTextList) {
                canvas.drawText(s, leftViewPadding + (getHighestLeftTextWidth() / 2), ((topViewPadding + unitHeight * i) - unitHeight / 2) + (textPaint.getTextSize() / 2), textPaint);
                i++;
            }
        }

//        Draw bottom arrow
        int boxWidth = totalViewWidth - (rightViewPadding + leftX);
        int width = boxWidth / totalBottomCount;
        int lineHeight = bottomViewPadding / 4;
        canvas.drawLine(leftX, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, leftX, (totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding) + lineHeight, linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(centerX, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, centerX, (totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding) + lineHeight, linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, (totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding) + lineHeight, linePaint);
        canvas.drawText("-30", leftX, totalViewHeight - (bottomViewPadding / 2) + (textPaint.getTextSize() / 2), textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("0", centerX, totalViewHeight - (bottomViewPadding / 2) + (textPaint.getTextSize() / 2), textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("30", totalViewWidth - rightViewPadding, totalViewHeight - (bottomViewPadding / 2) + (textPaint.getTextSize() / 2), textPaint);

        for (int i = 1; i < totalBottomCount; i++) {
            if (i != totalBottomCount / 2) {
                canvas.drawLine(leftX + (width * i), totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding, leftX + (width * i), (totalViewHeight - bottomViewPadding) + lineHeight, linePaint);
                canvas.drawText((i * 10) - 30 + "", leftX + (width * i), totalViewHeight - (bottomViewPadding / 2) + (textPaint.getTextSize() / 2), textPaint);

            }
        }


        int unitWidth = boxWidth / totalBarRatio;
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalBarRatio; i++) {
            barPercentage.add(leftX + (unitWidth * i));
        }

    }

    private float getHighestLeftTextWidth() {
        String text = "";
        for (String s : leftTextList) {
            if (s.length() > text.length()) {
                text = s;
            }
        }
        return textPaint.measureText(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int mViewWidth = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int mViewHeight = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(mViewWidth, mViewHeight);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int preferred = 0;
        if (leftTextList != null) {
            preferred = leftTextList.size() * (barWidth);
        }
        return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int preferred = 222;
        return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
    }

    private int getMeasurement(int measureSpec, int preferred) {
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        int measurement;
        switch (MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec)) {
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                measurement = specSize;
                break;
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                measurement = Math.min(preferred, specSize);
                break;
            default:
                measurement = preferred;
                break;
        }
        return measurement;
    }

}
```

And i have used

```
 public void setDataList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    dataList = list;
    postInvalidate();
}
```

To update the view with new data from my Activity but postInvalidate doesnot call onDraw.

Answer (score 1):

According to android docs [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()) method  can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window. So you have to call your `setDataList()` from other than UI thread or use the `invalidate()` method to update the `View` from UI thread like below.

```
public void setDataList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    dataList = list;
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Hi Chandrakanth i am calling setDataList from a onProgressChanged method how can i call setDataList From that method do i need to use view.post ?

Comment: onProgressChanged()? Where is that method?.

Comment: In my Activty I have a seekBar i need to update the graph on correspondent to the progress change

Comment: Ok fine then replace postInvalidate() with invalidate() in in your setDataList()  method.

Comment: Not working,    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        dataList.set(3, 50);
        setDataList(dataList);
        return true;
    } but post invalidate working onTouch i have tried with both

Comment: Is your Custom view working in properly in other than touch or seek bar methods.

Comment: didnt checked but by calling postInvalidate from on touch the view get updated but in onProgressChange doesnt i tried both invalidate and postinvalidate